# village lost from Google account

Tags: clash-of-clans

Hey I have lost my village call as lonelison willa from my Google account n I've sing in with a new village in that sam account so how do I get back my old village in that same account????

Answer (score 1):

If you've linked a village to a Google+ account, you cannot link another one to the same account. That first village is permanently tied to the Google+ account.

If you believe that you have linked another village to your account, then there's two possibilities of what happened:

- You did not actually link your account. Clearing your cache, starting a new village, and signing back into your Google+ account should fix this.
- You linked a different Google+ account. You will need to find the old Google+ account to get it back.
- You did not actually link your old village to a Google+ account. If this happens, then you will need to contact SuperCell to have your village restored. Per [the wiki article](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Recovering_a_lost_village_that_wasn%27t_linked_to_GC_or_GPlus):

> Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open the Clash of Clans application.
> 2. Go to **In Game Settings**.
> 3. Make sure you are connected to a Google+ account, so your old village will get linked to it.
> 4. Press **Help and Support** which is found via the **In Game Settings** menu.
> 5. Press **Report an Issue**.
> 6. Press **Other Problem**.
>      If you can't access the 'in game report an issue' feature, please email support at clashofclans.android@supercell.net and support will help you as soon as possible.
>
> **If you have emailed them directly you must include the details of the new village as well!**
>
> Provide all the details of your problem and village. **DO NOT DELETE THE PRE-POPULATED DATA!**
>
> The following information will be required:
>
> - Name of the old village:
> - Name of the clan your lost village is part of:
> - Town Hall level of the lost village:
> - Date and time of your last playing session on the lost village:
>
> **It is recommended that you DO NOT PASS TOWN HALL 4 on the new village, this may cause problems in the recovery procedure!**
>
> Support may take up to 2-4 weeks to reply.